# codeigniter consultas sql traer datos

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, subconsultas

hola comunidad espero me pudan ayudar hago esto para traer mis datos de la base de datos pero me imprime todos lo datosyo solo quiero ver mi correo, nombre completo,nivel y id

quero traer mi nivel para poder comparar con mi nivel se seccion y me pueda abrir ciertas pestañas

```
          <?php
       //var_dump($data)
    
      //echo $data;
      $id = $this->session->userdata('id');este 

  $data=$this->User_model->getUser($id);


// Convert array to string by using implode function.

  //echo $data;
  echo '<pre>';   var_export($data)
  //echo $data->row['id'];

?>
```

en lugar de comparar mi seccion con 1 quiero compararlo con $nivel

```
    if($this->session->nivel==1){
?>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="usuarios" class="nav-link">
              <i class="far fa-user"></i>
              <p>
                Usuarios
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
          <?php
}

?>
```

**modelo**

```
    public function getUser($id){
    $this->db->select("u.id,                 u.correo,        u.password,       u.NumeroDeEmpleado,  
        u.Nombre,              u.ApellidoM,     u.ApellidoP,        
        u.CURP,                u.RFC,           u.NSS,              u.FechaNacimiento,  
        u.Originario,          u.Alergias,      u.Domicilio,        u.Sexo,  
        u.Tipodesangre,        u.EstadoCIvil,   u.FechaLaboral,     u.Puesto, 
        u.Antiguedad,          u.Area,          u.FechaRealLaboral, u.NombreFamiliar,
        u.TelefonoFamiliar,    u.Parentesco,    u.Nivel,           u.Banco, 
        u.NumTarjeta,           u.Telefono,      u.Edad,           u.licencia,  u.filename,
"    );
    $this->db->from("usuarios u");
    $this->db->where("u.id",$id);

    $result=$this->db->get();
    return $result->row();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

crea una funcion en tu modelo User_model como esta donde obtendras solamente el nivel del usuario.

```
public function getNivelUser($id)
{
    $this->db->select('id, Nombre, correo, Nivel');
    $this->db->from('usuarios');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $row = $this->db->get()->row();
    //verificamos el retorno
    if (isset($row)) {
        return $row;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

y en el controlador

```
$nivel=$this->User_model->getNivelUser($id);
```

otra cosa, si tu modelo getUser() trae todas las columnas de la tabla usuarios puedes hacer algo como esto, que es lo mismo pero mas corto y ordenado.

```
 public function getUser($id){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from("usuarios");
$this->db->where("id",$id);

$result=$this->db->get();
return $result->row();
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132374/discussion-on-answer-by-sergio-codeigniter-consultas-sql-traer-datos).