# CodeIgniter consultas SQL

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Buenos dias comunidad espero me puedan ayudar quiero hacer una consulta la cual si el correo de mi seccion es igual al `NumeroDeEmpleado` de mi base de datos me sume todas las cantidades

**modelo**

```
public function getCantidadAsignadaUser($correo)
{
    $this->db->select('cantidad');
    $this->db->from('viaticos');
    $this->db->where('NumeroDeEmpleado', $correo);
    $row = $this->db->get()->row();
    //verificamos el retorno
    if (isset($row)) {
        //retornamos solamente el valor de viaticos
        return $row->cantidad;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**controlador**

```
 $correo = $this->session->userdata('correo'); 
 $gatos_viaticos =$this->Viatic_model->getCantidadAsignadaUser($correo);
```

**vista**

```
<a href="myprofile" class="d-block">Cantidad <?php echo $gatos_viaticos; ?></a>
```

Solo me muestra la primer cantidad registrada y yo quiero que me sume todas las cantidades

[En base a esta pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/503475/codeigniter-consultas-sql-traer-datos/503483#503483)

Comment: ¿Qué versión de CodeIgniter estas usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si utilizas la v3 de CodeIgniter en la [documentación referente a los Query Builder](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) existe una función llamada `$this->db->select_sum()` y recibe como parametro el nombre de tu columna de tu tabla, tal como:

```
public function getCantidadAsignadaUser($correo)
{
    $this->db->select_sum('cantidad','cantidad');
    $this->db->from('viaticos');
    $this->db->where('NumeroDeEmpleado', $correo);
    $row = $this->db->get()->row();
    //verificamos el retorno
    if (isset($row)) {
        //retornamos solamente el valor de viaticos
        return $row->cantidad;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo estas haciendo una consulta en donde `NumeroDeEmpleado = $correo` es correcto que solo te muestre la primera coincidencia, si lo que quieres es sumar todos los valores tienes que utilizar `SUM()`:

```
$this->db->select("(SELECT SUM(cantidad) 
FROM viaticos 
WHERE NumeroDeEmpleado = $correo) AS cantidad", false);
$query = $builder->get();
```

De esta forma obtendrás la suma que requieres.

Comment: me manda error en la variable builder

Comment: tienes que cambiarla por $this->db-> que tienes en tu codigo

Comment: Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$correo' in 'where clause'

SELECT (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM viaticos WHERE NumeroDeEmpleado = $correo) AS cantidad

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/test3/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691  correo lo tomo de mi seccion

Comment: Utiliza comillas dobles "" en lugar de simples ''

Comment: funciono gracias

Comment: Si esta respuesta te funciono márcala como correcta